# no se porque no me toma otros números que no sean 25, 35,45,55, etc. solo toma números terminados en 5

Tags: c#

no se porque no me toma otros números que no sean 25, 35,45,55, etc. solo toma números terminados en 5, pero si pongo otro numero que no termine en 5, no toma el  segundo dígito, ejemplo: 63. Toma el 6 y escribe "sesenta", después le agrego un "y" para seguidamente colocar "tres", supuesta mente tendría que hacer eso, pero no toma el tres por algún motivo que desconozco. agradecería que me indicaran donde esta el error o que me propongan una solución. El problema podría ser mucho más fácil, haciéndolo con puros if pero mi catedrático, nos dijo que era obligatorio hacerlo la estructura switch.

```
double a;
        double c;
        double d = 0;
        string f = null;
        double n;
        string s = null;

        Console.WriteLine("ingrese un numero");
        n = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        a = Math.Truncate(n / 10);
        switch (a)
        {
            case 2:
                s = "veinte";
                break;
            case 3:
                s = "treinta";
                break;
            case 4:
                s = "cuarenta";
                break;
            case 5:
                s = "cincuenta";
                break;
            case 6:
                s = "sesenta";
                break;
            case 7:
                s = "setenta";
                break;
            case 8:
                s = "ochenta";
                break;
            case 9:
                s = "noventa";
                break;

        }

        double w = (n / 10);
        c = w - a;
        d = c * 10;



        switch (d)
        {
            case 1:
                f = "uno";
                break;
            case 2:
                f = "dos";
                break;
            case 3:
                f = "tres";
                break;
            case 4:
                f = "cuatro";
                break;
            case 5:
                f = "cinco";
                break;
            case 6:
                f = "seis";
                break;
            case 7:
                f = "siete";
                break;
            case 8:
                f = "ocho";
                break;
            case 9:
                f = "nueve";
                break;

        }

        Console.WriteLine(s + " y " + f);














        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema es que en el switch estas preguntando por un int y el resultado de la multiplicación es un double, entonces al entrar al segundo switch nunca va a coincidir. Lo que tenes que hacer es crear una nueva variable y asignarle el valor de "d" y a esta misma convertirla en int.

```
double w = (n / 10);
        c = w-a;
        d = c * 10;
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(d);
```